# What is the significance of the code at right of variable declaration in COBOL?

Tags: cobol

I was studying COBOL code and I did not understand the number at the right of the code line:

```
007900     03  EXAMPLE-NAME       PIC S9(17)  COMP-3.              EB813597
```

the first number is about position of that line in code, the second is about column's position  (like how many 'tabs' you are using), the third is type of variable, but the fourth (**COMP-3**) and mainly the last (**EB813597**) I did not understand.

What does it mean?

Comment: For `COMP-3` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/799500/9170346. The `EB813597` is treated as a comment and has no meaning in the COBOL language.

Comment: Thanks @RickSmith

Comment: I've seen a lot of rubble like this EB813597 in old code where it was used to follow changes in the code.
If your shop does follow the changes another way(probably more modern source management tools like endevor), then it can be get rid of without pity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns >= 72 are ignored. So  **EB813597** is ignored. It could be a change id from the last time it was changed or have some site specific meaning  e.g. EB could be the initials of the person who last changed it.

**Comp-3** - is the type of numeric. It is bit like using int or double in C/java. In Comp-3 (packed-decimal) 123 is stored as x'123c'. Alternatives to comp-3 include **comp** - normally big endian binary integer, **comp-5** (like int / long in C)

```
007900     03  EXAMPLE-NAME       PIC S9(17)  COMP-3.              EB813597
 (a)      (b)  Field-Name         (c)  (d)    Usage (numeric type)


a - line-number ignored by the compiler
b - level-number it provides a method of grouping fields together

      01  Group.
          03 Field-1 ...
          03 Field-2 ... 

    field-1 and field-2 belong to group. it is a bit like struct in c

        struct {
            int field_1;
            int field-2;
            ...
       }
c) PIC (picture) tells us the field picture follows.
d) fields picture in this case it is a signed field with 17 decimal digits
Comp-3 - usage - how the field stored
```

So in summary **EXAMPLE-NAME** is a **Signed** numeric field with **17** decimal digits and it is stored as **Comp-3** (packed decimal).

Comment: Nice answer @BruceMartin ! It was clear, objective, simple and answered questions perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: also sometimes if you are using a code generator (like NETRON) it will add tags to the far right that are relevant. In NETRON, the name of frame the code was pulled from will be placed in those columns far to the right.